# how to integrate hangout api inside angular 2.1+?

Tags: typescript, angular2-http, google-api-js-client, hangouts-api

I had tried using hangout button but it is not the exact solution for what i am looking for. I want to get url generated by hangout button without using hangout button. I am not able to use gapi in angular 2.1. So i am using http module. I  have access to calender api. I cannot use external js files in my project.